# How to skip corrupt (non-serializable) messages in Spring Kafka Consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

This question is for Spring Kafka, related to [Apache Kafka with High Level Consumer: Skip corrupted messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904383/apache-kafka-with-high-level-consumer-skip-corrupted-messages)

Is there a way to configure Spring Kafka consumer to skip a record that cannot be read/processed (is corrupt)?

I am seeing a situation where the consumer gets stuck on the same record if it cannot be deserialized. This is the error the consumer throws.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate: no long/Long-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value
```

The consumer polls the topic and just keeps printing the same error in a loop till program is killed.

In a @KafkaListener that has the following Consumer factory configurations,

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

Comment: i believe consumer never struck on one record, if you see that error message multiple times it means it happened to multiple records

Comment: can you update JSON payload and model mapper class?

Comment: @Deadpool The consumer is stuck on the same message. I verified it by the logs and the consumer group's offset. I resolved the JSON serialization error, but the aim of my question was to find out a way to skip this message altogether.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#error-handling-deserializer

If you can't move to that `2.2` version, consider to implement your own and return `null` for those records which can't be deserialized properly.

The source code is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.java

Comment: You can also use the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to advance past the bad the record. See the `--shift-by` option. But the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` is intended for handling this in a production application.

Comment: ```ErrorHandlingDeserializer``` has been deprecated you can now use ```ErrorHandlingDeserializer2``` the same way

Comment: How could this be used with Avro which is `KafkaAvroDeserializer`? Thanks.

Comment: Please, raise a new SO question

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using older version of kafka, in a @KafkaListener set the following Consumer factory configurations.

```
 Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomDeserializer.class);
```

Here is the code for CustomDeserializer:

```
 import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    public class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object>
    {
        @Override
        public void configure( Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize( String topic, byte[] data )
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Object object = null;
            try
            {
                object = mapper.readValue(data, Object.class);
            }
            catch ( Exception exception )
            {
                System.out.println("Error in deserializing bytes " + exception);
            }
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public void close()
        {
        }
    }
```

Since I want my code to be generic enough to read any kind of json, 
object = mapper.readValue(data, Object.class); I am converting it to Object.class. And as we are catching exception here, it won't be retried once read.

Comment: But how to handle Null value after that?

Comment: @LexSav you can always add a null check before parsing the data, if this is what you are asking. And for object we are assigning null initially so it is upto you how you want to handle that in the calling function.